# How much does salary go up after probation period?

Tags: salary, united-states, raise, probation

For an entry level technical position requiring a bachelor's degree, if HR begins the salary negotiations by stating that there will be a significant increase after six months, and another increase after another six months, what does this mean?  Is there a flat general figure, or approximate percentage, you can tell me, based on your observations?

Reason for asking: hoping this will help us develop a figure to state during the salary negotiations.

Notes: area in question (in the U.S.) has salaries that are slightly below national average; company is in a period of expansion; company currently has about 500 employees.

Edit: For the purposes of this question, please assume that the contract, when it gets written, *does* spell out the two raises.  (I have read other threads have made clear that one does have to be careful about that.)  My question has to do with trying to calculate backwards to arrive at a figure and a negotiation strategy.  (Reason: We are having trouble figuring out what the entry level rate for this type of position is.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no said or assumed percentage that it will go up. To some companies, which gave no raises to their employees for years, 3% is a significant raise, to some others it is nothing.

Unless you see a figure written on employment contract, assume you will not be getting a raise after the probationary period and be happy whatever they throw at your way. As a fresh graduate, most probably you are not in a position to ask them to put a certain percentage number in to your contract. So, start working there. See what they will bestow upon you and figure out if it is worth staying with this company for the long term.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not mentioned in your contract or elsewhere then assume that you may not get a raise.

But if you do be pleasantly surprised after just 6 months of working for them.

I think you need to get a bit more time under the belt before asking for more money. 6 Months is the usually amount of time to start picking up the ropes.